# E-visa for India cruise

Tags: visas, transit, india, cruising

I will be on a Celebrity Constellation cruise in February that stops in three ports in India, for a total of four days (overnight in Mumbai on the ship). Is one e-visa sufficient for all of this? Other ports are Cochin and Goa, all entry points for e-visas. Having trouble getting a straight answer on this as there have been many changes in the past year.

Comment: Thanks for that David. However, I have heard that when you are on a cruise ship, three ports in the same country (India) only counts as one entry in which case one evisa is enough. Having trouble getting confirmation of that. Hoping to hear from cruisers who have done this.

Comment: @LDTerra I have no idea. Has the OP asked the cruse line?

Answer (score 3):

We are just back from the exact same cruise in india on Celebrity Constellation (Dec 18) - we had a multiple entry visa, but talking to other guests on same cruise majority had e-visa's, with some of them checking with Celebrity that e-visa was enough.  We visited Cochin, New Magalore, Goa & Mumbai.  (UK Passport).  My friend is also going on same cruise in March 19 and spoke to Celebrity and they said e-visa was fine - only if you intended going out of india i.e. Sri Lanka or golden triangle - and not just the ports the cruise was stopping at would you need full visa.

Comment: I would definately check with Celebrity

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Jan at 2 January 2019 was absolutely right at that time - but since there has been a major change in the Indian visa system in the spring of 2019 it's not right anymore after that. Since then there is an electronic-visa system with e-Tourist-visa valid for only one month (and only a right for single-entry) and another one's valid for one year and a third one's valid for even 5 years (both with the right for multiple-entry). So with this new visa you can use the e-visa (more specific the e-tourist-visa) when you are on a cruise in India and will stop in more ports in India - subject to the condition that you're allowed to enter the country with the e-visa on the specific port you're stopping in. See the website of the Indian government https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html for this details.

Comment: Please include a link to the government web page to which you refer in your answer.

Comment: At the moment that is anyway an academic question as travelling to India isn't possible for the time being. At the [website of IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) you can see that regular (means touristic) travel to India is still not possible. When you click in the map on India you'll read "Flights to India are suspended until 31 March 2021"

Comment: Beside IATA there are many websites providing information on the (im)possibilities for travel to India at this time. The difficulty is that the Indian government only informs at the end of the month if travel with tourist-visa will be possible in the following month. You can i.e. see on gov.uk or on the regularly updated website [visa Indien](https://visumbeantragen.at/indien) what influence covid-19 and countermeasures have on travelling to India and which possibilities still exist for travel (such as an OCI- or a PIO-card) when you click on "coronavirus rules in India" in the yellow section.

Answer (score 1):

Only one e-visa required. You enter India at the port of Mumbai. The ship STAYS in India (within territorial waters) for the subsequent stops in Cochin and Goa. Again, you ENTER India at Mumbai and you EXIT India at Goa. One entry, one exit, one e-visa.

Answer (score 0):

On [this Government of India webpage](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html), the text says:

*The validity of e-Visa (except e-Conference visa) will be 60 days from the date of arrival in India. In case of e-Conference visa, the validity will be 30 days from the date of arrival in India. **Double entry is permitted on e-Tourist visa** and e-Business visa. Triple entry will be permitted on e-Medical visa and e-Medical Attendant visa. Only single entry is permitted on e-Conference visa.* (emphasis added)

Thus, you'll need two eVisas for the three Indian ports.